# Cannot inherit from a type that is not marked with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute.

Tags: iis-7, .net-4.0

I am getting the following error on one of the servers, but not on the other. The project files are identical. I assume there is some difference in configuration, but I cannot find it.

> Cannot inherit from a type that is not marked with
>   DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute. Consider marking the
>   base type with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute, or
>   removing them from the derived type

What kind of setting/feature installed/role/assembly missing or similar might cause this difference?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) error.